# Where does iTunesArtwork image get displayed?

Tags: ios, app-store, itunesartwork

I forgot to replace the Cocos2D default iTunesArtwork file with a proper one. But when I tried browsing my app page, in iTunes app and website, it doesn't seem to use this file anywhere. So I don't know if I should be worrying about having this wrong file or not since I don't know where it will appear.

In this [Technical Q&A](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html) page, it says that iTunesArtwork is used in **Ad Hoc iTunes**. But where is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iTunesArtwork is the file that is used by iTunesConnect when displaying your app's logo on the store.

It's optional, and most people choose to keep their bundle sizes small and just upload the artwork to iTunesDirectly rather than adding it to their app.

The format and sizes for this and other icons are described in A [Developer Q&A 1686](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link! I see, so iTunesArtwork is optional, and may not be used anywhere since you can upload and override this image in iTunesConnect.

Answer (score 2):

From [iOS human interface guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW2)

> **Create a large version of your app icon for display in the App Store**.
>   Although it’s important that this version be instantly recognizable as
>   your app icon, it can be subtly richer and more detailed. There are no
>   visual effects added to this version of your app icon.
>
> For the App Store, create a large version of your app icon in two
>   sizes so that it looks good on all devices:
>
> 512 x 512 pixels 1024 x 1024 pixels (high resolution); recommended **Be
>   sure to name these versions of your app icon iTunesArtwork and
>   iTunesArtwork@2x, respectively**.